# Why aren't arguments working in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to learn how to code with Java and I am now just learning arguments using Eclipse. I am reading the book *Sam's Teach Yourself Java in 24 Hours* and I am following the book completely; however, it is not working in eclipse. My code is the following:

```
public class BlankFiller {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("The " + arguments[0]
                + " " + arguments[1] + " fox "
                + "jumped over the "
                + arguments[2] + " dog.");
    }
}
```

Then I put my arguments in by going to **Run** → **Run Configurations** → **Arguments** and I type in "retromingent purple lactose-intolerant" into the Program Arguments tab, hit apply then run but it just gives me this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem
        arguments cannot be resolved to a variable
        arguments cannot be resolved to a variable
        arguments cannot be resolved to a variable

        at BlankFiller.main(BlankFiller.java:4)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: About error: substituite arguments with args where you see waved red underline

Comment: Once again, SO is lacking a `retromingent` tag.

Comment: Buy a better book. Specifically, one *not* published by Sam's.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You named the formal parameter `args` but you are trying use the variable `arguments` in the body of the method. Change one or the other so they match.

By the way—welcome to SO. In the future, please don't post your code on a separate web site like that. Unless it is absolutely necessary to do otherwise, include everything that is relevant directly in the question itself.

Comment: Considering the OP's level of experience, I think it's worth noting that the de facto standard is to name the parameter in question "args".

Comment: @BuzzKillington - It's certainly less typing. However, it's never too early to learn that parameter names are pretty much arbitrary.

Comment: Thank you so much! I typed my code into the SO's editor and it said I did something incorrect. Something about having to have 4 blank lines before and after my code so I decided to just use links instead. But anyways, your correction worked so thank you!

Comment: @clownchad it takes some getting used to but every line of code must be indented by 4 spaces (in addition to your normal indentation). Easiest way is to paste your code, highlight it all and press either the code button in the edit toolbar, or Ctrl+k. That will indent your code for you and it will become a code block.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public static void main(String[] arguments)
```

You had named the `String[]` parameter as `args`, but were referencing it as `arguments`. The name you use doesn't really matter - as long as is the same in both parts.